# Not hitting with harrier?

Tags: lawbreakers

At first I thought it might be me but I'm not that sure so I'm curious if others are having any similar issue with Harrier. When you use your right click and it connects to the enemy, sometimes there's no hit registration with her primary fire unless you stop firing and hit them again? Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is this a design issue maybe?

Comment: I thought I just sucked with Harrier...

Comment: Is there a link to a post where they've acknowledged this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug on the PC Side and will be addressed in the next upcoming patch.